# How to check if JSON is nested or not in Java?

Tags: java, json

I have this JSON:

```json
{
    "id": 2643743,
    "dt": 1485789600,
    "clouds": {
        "all": 90
    }
}
```

In this JSON, how can I check for a key that has a nested JSON? For example, how can I check if clouds have nested JSON?

```
JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&APPID=916c290adb437e1cc53eab01798225ed");
Iterator keys = json.keys();
Iterator inskeys = json.keys();
String keyStr = null;
while(keys.hasNext()) {
    keyStr = (String) keys.next();
    Object keyvalue = json.get(keyStr);
    Object keyType = keyvalue.getClass().getSimpleName();
    ...
```

Comment: Post what you tried. At least say which of the dozens of JSON parsing APIs you're using.

Comment: Well, ... Why not check the type of the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is simple example:

```
String JSON = "{\"id\":2643743,\"dt\":1485789600,\"clouds\":{\"all\":90}}";    
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON);
    JSONObject getSth = jsonObject.getJSONObject("clouds");
```

Comment: You forgot to escape the double quotes.

Comment: Depending on the libraries he's using for JSON parsing, this may very well be incorrect. For JEE, it should work though.